# How to use ScrollView control in vertical line Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want my scrollview not "scrolling" down and yes from right and left side, like a Pivot!

```
<ScrollViewer Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
    AllowDrop="False" BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="True"
    HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" IsHoldingEnabled="True" >
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Height="90" Width="386" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollViewer Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" Background="Blue">
    <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor" />
</ScrollViewer>
```